# Do I need a special recipe for mini cheesecakes?

Tags: baking, cheesecake, recipe-scaling

I found a bunch of mini pie tins on sale at the grocery store and decided that instead of a regular sized cheesecake I would make mini ones for Thanksgiving.

I've yet to decide on a recipe, whether to go with straight pumpkin cheesecake, a layered cheesecake, or a marbled, but I do know I want to make the smaller ones.

I know that it's unlikely, but do I need a specific recipe for the smaller cheesecakes, or will a full-size, but divided recipe work? Also, in the case of a full-size recipe, is it worth layering or marbling a mini cheesecake?

Comment: I've only done it once, and I want to say that I changed the cooking times (and used Vanilla Wafers instead of trying to pack down tiny amounts of crumbs).  But for the equal size -- use a disher ... it'll make your life a lot easier.  For the marbling, if it's thick enough, I'd use two smaller dishers (one scoop to one side, another on top to the other side).   If  it's thinner, I'd fill two pastry bags, and try to squirt them both at the same time ... or chill the filling first, and then scoop)

Answer (score 1):

A full-sized recipe should be fine for putting the mini-cakes together. The taste of your cheesecake will stay the same regardless of size, so long as your ingredients are mixed well and you don't overfill the cups of your pan. Marbling shouldn't be a problem either.

You may want to watch your cooking time. The cakes will be smaller, so it won't take as much time in the oven to cook all the way through. I'd set the timer for half the time that the original recipe calls for. If the mini-cheesecakes aren't done by then, monitor very closely for the next couple of minutes. It won't take much more time than that.